# jq simple toggle for multiple elements

Tags: jquery, toggle

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
$('#toggle').click(function() {
$('.toggle').slideToggle('fast');
return false;
});

    });
</script>


<a href="#" id="toggle">show-hide</a><br />
<div class="toggle" style="display:none;">test</div>

<a href="#" id="toggle2">show-hide</a><br />
<div class="toggle" style="display:none;">test2</div>
```

Hello, I Need to make work this multiple toggle, for now he reveals all rows on click

Comment: So whats the issue ? it is toggling multiple items http://jsfiddle.net/PgKRX/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.nextAll(':first')` to target the specific element

```
  $(function () {
      $('a').click(function () {
          $(this).nextAll('.toggle:first').slideToggle('fast');
          return false;
      });
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/8s73u/)

---

**Solution #1**

You could give the links you want to click a class like this

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" class="linkClick" id="toggle">show-hide</a><br />
<div class="toggle" style="display:none;">test</div>

<a href="#" class="linkClick" id="toggle2">show-hide</a><br />
<div class="toggle" style="display:none;">test2</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.linkClick').click(function () {
      $(this).nextAll('.toggle:first').slideToggle('fast');
      return false;
});
```

---

**Solution #2**

or you could use Attribute-starts-with selector `^=`

```
  $('a[id^="toggle"]').click(function () {
      $(this).nextAll('.toggle:first').slideToggle('fast');
      return false;
  });
```

Comment: is it possible somehow rework this code, since others links on page are getting untouchable?

Comment: Yeah you can use either add class to the elements you want to  have the click function on or use attribute-starts-with selector  $('a[id^="toggle"]') @user3189476

Answer (score 0):

Use the `attribute starts with selector`, and then by using the `current element` get the next div with that specified class and then slide it.

Try,

```
$(function() {
     $('a[id^="toggle"').click(function() {
        $(this).nextAll('.toggle').first().slideToggle('fast');
     });
 });
```

Comment: where r u? wr is pendrive?